# PHP/jQuery : jQuery posts variable but PHP not reading it

Tags: php, jquery

```
echo "function disp_player (playerID) {";
    echo "$.post('editor.php', {'idval': playerID});";

    echo "alert(playerID);";
    echo "alert(" . $playerlist[$_POST['idval']][0] . ");";
```

I'm writing a PHP script that is supposed to change text based on a selection made from a drop down.

The page can be viewed here - http://superonlinehockey.com/editor.php

The first alert works and the playerID is output.  Setting $playerlist[$_POST['idval']][0] to a static value like $playerlist[770][0] also works.  Using Firebug, I see that the value is added to post and, also using Firebug, it looks like the code all works.  However, that second alert gives me an 'Undefined' when I would expect it ot be the same as the first alert.

Can anyone help me?  Am I posting wrong?  I'm new to jQuery so I'm not sure how this is supposed to work but, based on what I do know, I don't see anything wrong with my code.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
echo '$.post(\'editor.php\', {\'idval\': playerID});';
```

its because in php between `"` $some will behave as variable

and

```
echo "alert('" . $playerlist[$_POST['idval']][0] . "');";
```

[**Codepad**](http://codepad.org/CwZuJ04n)

Comment: I tried this but, unfortuantely, the same thing occurred - the $_POST['idval'] is still undefined.

If you need more code from me to understand what is happening, I can provide it.

This is my call to jQuery - echo "<script src=\"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js\"></script>"; 

That is working for another script I run on the page, so I'm pretty sure it isn't my jQuery call.